# ToolStripButton Tooltip location is wrong

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, toolstrip, toolstripbutton

I have a ToolStrip that have a couple of `ToolStripButtons` with tooltips. When I highlight any of the buttons the tooltip shows just fine but its location is a bit far from the cursor.

I got no idea why is this happening and I tried to workaround it but to no avail. I included a screenshot to show the problem.

[image]

Comment: There is no code to show. And as for what I've tried, I tried to get a hold of the tooltip component of the toolstripbutton so I can change its location. But ToolstripButtons only have ToolTipText property, no actual tooltip component or so. I also tried looking for events that are related. edit: I tried to create a new form and a new toolstrip, same issue is happening. So I don't think it has anything to do with the controls that are in the main form.

Comment: The only thing I can think of right now to solve this, is to disable the Tooltips shown by the `ToolStrip`, hook up the Hover event for the `ToolStrip`, and show tooltips manually via a `ToolTip` control. Which will require some programming but I guess I'll opt for this if no one comes with a solution :)